# Uses of Qt debug libs

Tags: c++, debugging, qt

I was downloading Qt libraries from Qt site and I noticed "qt-mac-opensource-4.8.0-debug-libs.dmg", but could not figure out it use.

I think it is for those people who wants to extend Qt. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

they provide source code as well with binary, but i suggest you to checkout code form their [Git repository](https://qt.gitorious.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Debug libs of Qt are useful for any Qt development, as otherwise you won't be able to step into Qt-internal code to analyze a bug in your application (which cause might lie either in your code or in Qt). For that I usually prefer to compile Qt myself from git though.